# White spacing around navigation bar

Tags: html, css, whitespace, navigationbar

Alright, I couldn't find the answer by searching on the site, but I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS and I was wondering how to remove the white spacing around the navigation bar that I'm getting.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reisbureau</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerContent">
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" id="reisbureau">Reisbureau</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Over Ons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 8px 50px;
    color: dimgrey;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: black;
}
.nav {   
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 10;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:aliceblue;
}

#reisbureau {
    float: left;
}
```

**jsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/398aLrpy/

**Edit Note**
Contents of style.css are not included, so we can not actually see the nav bar as he does. Down voting on that reason alone.

I'm really clueless, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove default `margin` from `body` and `margin-top` from `ul` element:

```
body, ul{margin:0}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/znn448ab/1/)

Answer (score 0):

By default the browser's set some `padding` and/or `margin` to the `<body>` and/or `<html>`

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/23/)**

Comment: I've tried adding this code to my css but for some reason it still didn't work